# How to get text from textfield and pass it as a parameter to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, parameters, dom

I have a textfield which is supposed to change an element on the page with the text inside it when a submit button is pressed. I am passing the value to a javascript  function. It doesn't work, can anyone tell me how to do it/what i'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function submitText(string, id)
{
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = string;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id = "Datepara" style = "font-family:comic sans ms;color:orange;text-align:center;font-size:25px;">
Date Created: 24/9/12 <br /><br /><br/>
</p>
<input id = "changetext" type = "text" value = "Enter text to display text in this webpage!"/>
&nbsp;
<input id = "submit" type = "button" onclick = "submitText('Datepara','document.getElementById("changetext").value;'" value = "Submit" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this

```
<input id = "submit" type = "button" onclick = "submitText('Datepara','changetext')" value = "Submit" />
```

javascript

```
function submitText(divid,txtid)
{
   document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML = document.getElementById(txtid).value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I changed on your code: I switched the order of your parameters on submitText function, I removed the quotes around `document.getElementById("changetext").value` since you were passing a string and not the value of the input control

```
function submitText(id, string)
{
     document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = string;
}

<input id="submit" type="button" 
  onclick="submitText('Datepara', document.getElementById('changetext').value)"
  value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Hmmm.... still doesn't work... I'm not sending it to a server, just changing certain text on the page

Comment: @imulsion: sorry, I thought it was a submit type button. but submit is the name.

Answer (score 0):

`'document.getElementById("changetext").value;'` is a string literal, not the value property of a gEBId call.

`"submitText('Datepara','document.getElementById("` is the value of the `onclick` attribute. Watch your quotes.

`submitText(string, id)` takes a string then an id, not an id then a string.